# Package inside a package

Tags: plsql

Kindly advise me on below requirement:

I have two packages those run for different businesses in same database.

PACKAGE_1.PROCEDURE_1 - Doing some insert for year 2014 and later

PACKAGE_2.PROCEDURE_2 - Doing Insert prior to year 2014.

Now in one condition in package 1, procedure 1 is called which insert values in a table after of year 2014.

Requirement: I need to insert values before 2014 as well in same condition of package_1.procedure_1 that are in package_2.procedure_2.

Please advise if I call the package inside a package or how I can achieve this requirement.

Regards,

Amit Saroha

Comment: Yes, you can call routines in PACKAGE_1 from PACKAGE_2, and vice versa. Note that to call a routine in PACKAGE_2 from PACKAGE_1, the called package's spec must be compiled before the calling package's body is compiled or you'll get a compilation error when the calling package's body is compiled. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i have low reputation so i couldn't comment.

Its based on the conditions handled in PACKAGE_1.PROCEDURE_1 and PACKAGE_2.PROCEDURE_2

You can use like this during execution part,

```
If year<2014 then
 call PACKAGE_2.PROCEDURE_2 to insert
elsif year >2014 then
 call PACKAGE_1.PROCEDURE_1 to insert
end if;
```

Regrards,
Manivannan.M